# JSON.stringify and JSON.parse wont work in IE9

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net

Hi Guys I hope you can help as this is driving me up the wall !!

I am running local Vb.net web site and calling a javascript function to try to post JSON data to a php website on a web based server. My browser is IE9 and im using visual studio 2010

I started off trying to call JSON.stringify or JSON.parse and neither would work. 
I added into my .aspx page the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>` and it still didnt work
I downloaded a json file and referenced it locally from JSON.ORG and it still doesnt work.

When it gets to the line JSON.stringify - it returns a microsoft javascript error that JSON is not defined

I have spent two days trying to get this to run and could do with your help. Any thoughts ??

```
 function jsonSend() {
    var JSONJSON = {};
    var json = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_JsonTfr").value;
    JSONJSON['insc_users'] = json;
    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(JSONJSON);  //**this is where it fails**
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.thiswebsite.co.uk/receive.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonStr,
    success: function (data) {

    // handleLoginLocally(u, p);
    console.log('LOG.LOGIN: trying login using local storage');
    },
    error: function () {
    console.log('LOG.LOGIN: login remote server failed');

    // handleLoginLocally(u, p);
    console.log('LOG.LOGIN: trying login using local storage');
    }
    });
```

Comment: what are you doing with your JSONJSON object? You've got it set to an empty object and then you have JSONJSON['insc_users'] = json...I don't understand what you're doing here...what is the unknown value you get from the DOM? Apparently you're using webforms?

Comment: Im passing several objects into an array (JSONJSON) so that i can strip them out when they are posted over to my php file. I have only shown one here. The error that i get is 'microsoft javascript error that JSON is not defined'

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding  `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.01 Transitional//EN">` or `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Also check [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=json).

Comment: HTML4 doctype? Ew. why not recommend HTML5 only?

Comment: @JanDvorak:- Updated it with HTML5. Hope thats fine!!! Although OP may be get the idea what was missing!!

Comment: Not sure if the first doctype of this revision is valid. The second one is the correct way to specify HTML5

Comment: never mind. It seems both doctypes are valid. The shorter one is the preferred one, however.

Comment: I just pasted that into the first line of my .apsx page and tried to compile. i get the following error Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Comment: Added into the header page and it now compiles. but still not working

Comment: if I use eval to parse json that works, is there an equivalent to that to allow me to stringify ?

Comment: You are more vulnerable to attacks if using eval(). Also check out this:- http://json.org/

Comment: Also check out this:- https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: The website is internal and secure so I am not concerned about the security in this situation. If I copy and paste the JSON script I downloaded into the same script as the one I have posted above it works so I am now thinking it is how I am referencing the JSON.JS file ?